Ranorex remote execution of tests
How ranorex executes tests remotely. what is the technology it is using or any mechanism it is using for remote execution??. i want to implement the same in our product
im expecting how the ranorex is built in case of remote execution. the way of doing it programatically.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can create a script and run it from the CMD. If the remote computer is in the same network. It should not be a problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
